# Bring image up in Image Viewer WP7

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

On WP7 in Silverlight, is it possible to tell the OS to open up an image in the normal image viewer?
I have a bunch of thumbnails that the user can press to make big, but I don't feel like re-inventing the wheel as the built in image viewer is great. So can I bring up my image in that?

Thanks

Comment: Don't know if it would work, but you could try the MediaPlayerLauncher with an image url - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.mediaplayerlauncher_members(v=VS.92).aspx - but otherwise I don't think there's an API available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "normal image viewer" in WP7.

The pictures hub is a separate application which has it's own way of displaying images.

The only way to integrate with the pictures hub is as an "extras" app or by saving an image to the MediaLibrary.

If you want to show an image you must do this yourself. While this may mean a little more work it does mean you can create an experience which integrates directly with the rest of your app.